# How to draw a double horizontal line after head in all longtables?

Tags: longtable, hhline, hline

I want to create a latex style, which would enable to draw a double horizontal line after longtable heads automatically.

An important point I already have a lot of documents  which contains longtables with a single horizontal line after a head, so I need to add one horizontal line.

My first attempt is to add `\hline` to `\endfirsthead` definition:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\endfirsthead{\hline\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
  
    \hline head 1 & head 2 & head 3 \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
   
\end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

But there is no gap between two lines, so it looks like one bold line.
[image: first attempt]

How to fix this and solve the task properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\endfirsthead{\bottomrule[\arrayrulewidth] \LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firsthead}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
        
        \hline head 1 & head 2 & head 3 \\ \hline 
        \endfirsthead
        
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
        
    \end{longtable}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple to do with `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}

    \hline head 1 & head 2 & head 3 \\ \hhline{|=:=:=|}
    \endfirsthead

    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how to this automatically?

Comment: That seems quite hard, unless all your tables have the same number of columns.